# Javascript Object.freeze() does not prevent changes to object

Tags: javascript, oop

I am trying to understand the Object.freeze method of ECMAscript.

My understanding was that it essentially stops changes to all the properties of an object. MDN documentation says:

> Prevents new properties from being added to it; prevents existing properties from being removed; and prevents existing properties, or their enumerability, configurability, or writability, from being changed.

This does not seem to be the case, but perhaps I have misinterpreted the docs.

Here is my object, with its enumerable property exampleArray

```
function myObject()
{
    this.exampleArray = [];
}

var obj = new myObject();
obj.exampleArray[0] = "foo";
```

Now if I freeze the object, I would expect the exampleArray property to be frozen too, as in it can no longer be changed in any way.

```
Object.freeze(obj);
obj.exampleArray[1] = "bar";
console.log(obj.exampleArray.length); // logs 2
```

"bar" has been added to the array, thus the frozen object has been changed. My immediate solution is to just freeze the desired property:

```
Object.freeze(obj.exampleArray);
obj.exampleArray[2] = "boo";
```

Now changing the array throws an error, as desired.

However, I am developing my application and I don't yet know what will be assigned to my object. My use case is that I have some game objects which are initialized (from an XML file) when the game starts. After this, I do not want to be able to change any of their properties accidentally.

Perhaps I am misusing the freeze method? I would like to be able to freeze the whole object, a sort of recursive freeze. The best solution I can think of here is to loop through the properties and freeze each one.

I've already searched for this question and the only answer says it's an implementation bug. I am using the newest version of Chrome. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Half down this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze it says: **The following example shows that object values in a frozen object can be mutated (freeze is shallow).** So it seems to work as designed.

Answer (score 13):

Object.freeze is a shallow freeze.

If you look at the description in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze), it says:

> Values cannot be changed for data properties. Accessor properties (getters and setters) work the same (and still give the illusion that you are changing the value). **Note that values that are objects can still be modified, unless they are also frozen.**

If you want to deep-freeze an object, here's [a good recursive example](https://github.com/substack/deep-freeze/blob/master/index.js)

```js
function deepFreeze(o) {
  Object.freeze(o);

  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o).forEach(function(prop) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(prop)
    && o[prop] !== null
    && (typeof o[prop] === "object" || typeof o[prop] === "function")
    && !Object.isFrozen(o[prop])) {
        deepFreeze(o[prop]);
      }
  });

  return o;
}

function myObject() {
  this.exampleArray = [];
}

var obj = deepFreeze(new myObject());
obj.exampleArray[0] = "foo";
console.log(obj); // exampleArray is unchanged
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the property descriptors for the object to `writable:false`, `configurable:false` using `Object.defineProprties`; then call `Object.preventExtensions` on the object. See [How to create static array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40386767/how-to-create-static-array-in-javascript/40387821#40387821).