# Javascript Const object under Object.freeze() is still changing

Tags: javascript, constants

Why does the array `b`, in the code snippet below seem to change. This can be detected through the `console.log(b)`

Here is the code snippet:

```js
const b = Object.freeze([['O', 'O', ''], ['X', 'X', ''], ['O', 'X', '']])
cput = false
for (let i=1; i<10; i++){
    temp = [...b]
    if (b[Math.floor((i - 1) / 3)][(i - 1) % 3] == ''){
        temp[Math.floor((i - 1) / 3)][(i - 1) % 3] = (cput) ? 'O':'X'
        console.log(temp)
        console.log(b)
    }        
}
```

Essentially, I'm looking for a way to allow `temp` to be editted while `b` remains the constant.

Comment: You are not mutating `b`, but an element of `b`. Only `b` is frozen, the elements are not. All the references in `b` still point to the same arrays.

Comment: `Object.freeze()` is shallow freeze, it can only freeze 1 layer sub nodes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript Object.freeze() does not prevent changes to object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40407561/javascript-object-freeze-does-not-prevent-changes-to-object)

Comment: Is there a way I can completely freeze it, including the elements? Because, my ```temp``` is based on a copy of its data and the ```temp``` is now changing as a result

Comment: @An0n1m1ty See `deepFreeze()` in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze#What_is_shallow_freeze

Comment: and for the comparison use === when you code in js ;)

Comment: @LianSheng When I use deepfreeze, I can't assign a different value to temp

Comment: @Reyno also see the comment above

Comment: I can't create an answer because it will be close but remplace this :


let temp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(b));
/*temp = [...b]*/

Comment: @An0n1m1ty I think you can add some judgement to decide which is need freeze and which is not. For example, I think you can change this `if(value && typeof value === "object" && value !== temp) { deepFreeze(value); }`. It may your need.

Comment: @zerbene it works!! Do you want me to make a new question and give you credit?

Comment: Please note `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` will distort some values, like `RegExp`, `Date`, `Function`..., and custom ones.

Comment: Yes @An0n1m1ty why not, thank you very much (Just ask question and I will see it on your profil in the section question)

Comment: @zerbene, please see my new question

Comment: @An0n1m1ty ,thank you but I think it will be impossible because every body close the answer. So I'm happy that your code works, remind you that JSON.parse can be dangerous with some data type. And don't worry for the credit (it's just point ;) )