# Immutables and collections in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, immutable-collections

I'm trying to get my head around how to use Immutables in JavaScript/TypeScript without taking all day about it. I'm not quite ready to take the dive into Immutable.js, because it seems to leave you high and dry as far as type safety.

So let's take an example where I have an Array where the elements are all of Type MyType. In my Class, I have a method that searches the Array and returns a copy of a matching element so we don't edit the original. Say now that at a later time, I need to look and see if the object is in the Array, but what I have is the copy, not the original.

What is the standard method of handling this? Any method I can think of to determine whether I already have this item is going to take some form of looping through the collection and visiting each element and then doing a clunky equality match, whether that's turning both of them to strings or using a third-party library.

I'd like to use Immutables, but I keep running into situations like this that make them look pretty unattractive. What am I missing?

Comment: You wouldn't return a copy of the object in your array. You would return the object. If you later needed to mutate it, instead you would make a copy with the changes you need.

Comment: Assuming the object in the array is immutable, why would you make a copy of it?

Comment: That then puts the responsibility on the client code to use the object it got properly, which seems unwise. It's my own project so of course that is an option I have open, but on a larger project with multiple developers, that doesn't seem to be a good idea.

Comment: If you want to solve type safety, JavaScript isn't equipped for this and no library will help you. You can use Typescript or some static type checker with annotations though. You can use Immuatable.js with those.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship Then `Object.freeze` it if you don't trust them :-)

Comment: Immutable.js does have its own types, but it seems like the things that go into its collections are basically untyped.

Comment: @Bergi, it's not that I'm making a copy of the Array (AFAIK there is no way to make an Array immutable), I am making a copy of the object in the array so that any changes made to it are not reflected in the Array.

Comment: @Bergi, I don't think Object.freeze() does what you think it does.

Comment: _"AFAIK there is no way to make an Array immutable"_ Yes, this is possible [How to create static array in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40386767/how-to-create-static-array-in-javascript)

Comment: @AmyBlankenship The things that go into an array are untyped as well :-) As I said, typechecking is not the duty of Immutable.  Yes, you make a copy of the object, but you could just prevent changes to it using [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze)

Comment: Um, no they're not. An array with all objects of MyType is typed like this: `let myArr:MyType[]`. I appreciate you working to try to get your head around this as well, but it doesn't actually seem to me you're further forward than I am.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve?

Comment: If the item is in the collection, I want to replace it with one where one of the properties is incremented by one. If it is not in the collection, I want to replace it with one that has that property set to zero. But that doesn't seem to be relevant to the actual question, which is how to solve this basic problem when using immutables that are stored in a collection.

Comment: You can use the same approach and logic which you described to meet requirement. What is the definition of "immutable" that you are referencing at current Question?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that my solution is not "...the standard method of handling this." However, I think it at least is *a* way of doing what I think you're asking.

You write that you have a method that "...returns a copy of a matching element so we don't edit the original". Could you change that method so that it instead returns *both* the original *and* a copy?

As an example, the strategy below involves retrieving both an original element from the array (which can later be used to search by reference) as well as a clone (which can be manipulated as needed without affecting the original). There is still the cost of cloning the original during retrieval, but at least you don't have to do such conversions for every element in the array when you later search the array. Moreover, it even allows you to differentiate between array elements that are identical-by-value, something that would be impossible if you only originally retrieved a copy of an element. The code below demonstrates this by making every array element identical-by-value (but, by definition of what objects are, different-by-reference).

I don't know if this violates other immutability best practices by, e.g., keeping copies of references to elements (which, I suppose, leaves the code open to future violations of immutability even if they are not currently being violated...though you could [deep-freeze](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-freeze) the original to prevent future mutations). However it at least allows you to keep everything technically immutable while still being able to search by reference. Thus you can mutate your clone as much as you want but still always hold onto an associated copy-by-reference of the original.

```js
const retrieveDerivative = (array, elmtNum) => {
  const orig = array[elmtNum];
  const clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(orig));
  return {orig, clone};
};

const getIndexOfElmt = (array, derivativeOfElement) => {
  return array.indexOf(derivativeOfElement.orig);
};


const obj1 = {a: {b: 1}}; // Object #s are irrelevant.
const obj3 = {a: {b: 1}}; // Note that all objects are identical
const obj5 = {a: {b: 1}}; // by value and thus can only be
const obj8 = {a: {b: 1}}; // differentiated by reference.

const myArr = [obj3, obj5, obj1, obj8];

const derivedFromSomeElmt = retrieveDerivative(myArr, 2);

const indexOfSomeElmt = getIndexOfElmt(myArr, derivedFromSomeElmt);

console.log(indexOfSomeElmt);
```

Comment: As it happens, any of the objects can produce a clone of itself on request. So if you get an object, you can get a clone of the object by calling clone() on the object. I'm still trying to get my head around writing this without a halfway mishmash, because it seems like somewhere in there you have to draw a line where you're not fully going to make it immutable. And it feels like there's a lot of extra code around immutability--more than the code it's supposed to eliminate in defensive copying, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The situation you've described is one where a mutable datastructure has obvious advantages, but if you otherwise benefit from using immutables there are better approaches.

While keeping it immutable means that your new updated object is completely new, that cuts both ways: you may have a new object, but you also still have access to the original object! You can do a lot of neat things with this, e.g. chain your objects so you have an undo-history, and can go back in time to roll back changes.

So don't use some hacky looking-up-the-properties in the array. The problem with your example is because you're building a new object at the wrong time: don't have a function return a copy of the object. Have the function return the original object, and call your update using the original object as an index.

```
let myThings = [new MyType(), new MyType(), new MyType()];

// We update by taking the thing, and replacing with a new one.
// I'll keep the array immutable too
function replaceThing(oldThing, newThing) {
  const oldIndex = myThings.indexOf(oldThing);
  myThings = myThings.slice();
  myThings[oldIndex] = newThing;
  return myThings;
}

// then when I want to update it
// Keep immutable by spreading
const redThing = myThings.find(({ red }) => red);
if (redThing) {
  // In this example, there is a 'clone' method
  replaceThing(redThing, Object.assign(redThing.clone(), {
    newProperty: 'a new value in my immutable!',
  });
}
```

All that said, classes make this a whole lot more complex too. It's much easier to keep simple objects immutable, since you could simple spread the old object into the new one, e.g. `{ ...redThing, newProperty: 'a new value' }`. Once you get a higher than 1-height object, you may find immutable.js far more useful, since you can `mergeDeep`.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to figure this out because Angular 2 leans heavily on RxJS and not embracing Immutables leaves you with kind of a mish-mash approach, but I'm having a hard time developing an intuition of where to use it and where not to use it (and it feels like not using it everywhere still leaves a mish-mash).

Comment: Personally, I'd say assume you want it immutable unless something is potentially _very_ big (100MB+ in-memory), or there is a lot of data-model dependency (yours is a minor example, but if you had `const user = { name: josh }; shopCartMap.set(user, [{ name: 'pants'}, quantity: 1]); blogEntriesMap.set(user, [{ title: 'Immutability and You' }]);`, then you have a lot of relationships to update if the user changes immutably.)

`let` vs `const` are also really good indicators of mutable/immutable. An object/array declared `const` is a mutable datastore, and a `let` will be reassigned.